# NetSuite saved search customer retention group new customers with more than one order within 365 days

Tags: syntax, count, netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to group customers who have made purchases within the last 365 days that fit a specific set of criteria. The code below works great except when I add `COUNT({transaction.number}) > 1`. I have read NetSuite support and I think it is an aggregate function error but the system does not specify why it is failing. I expect the search to group my customers based on my conditions in the case statement below. Thank you!

The Saved search type is Customer. Criteria is Transaction Status: Billed and Transaction Type: Sales Order

```
CASE 
WHEN {datecreated} < to_date({today}-365) AND {transaction.datecreated} > to_date({today}-365) THEN 'Retained'   
WHEN {datecreated} BETWEEN to_date({today}-365) AND to_date({today})  AND {transaction.datecreated} > to_date({today}-365) THEN 'New' 
WHEN {datecreated} BETWEEN to_date({today}-365) AND to_date({today})  AND {transaction.datecreated} > to_date({today}-365) AND COUNT({transaction.number}) > 1 THEN 'Acquired' 
WHEN {custentity_date_lsa} < to_date({today}-365) THEN 'Lost'  
ELSE 'zOther' END`
```